# Manually build APK in Titanium Studio using CLI

Tags: android, node.js, build, titanium, npm

I'm using Titanium Studio to build an APP for android and I'm trying to manually build an APK to run on a external emulator, because titanium's emulator is too slow. I tried different things as export the project but there isn't this option in the studio. If I want to build the APK i need to run the emulator, wait it load and them the APK is build, so I'm trying a different aproach.

I run on console:

```
titanium build --platform android --project-dir "C:\Project"
```

And i have this return:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' eventError: spawn ENOENT

Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException <child_process.js:980:11>
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit <child_process.js:771:34>
```

Infos:

Titanium version: 3.1.2

Node version: 0.10.13

NPM version: 1.3.2

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too late, this is what I've been doing: 
1) Build for local emulator using titanium build -p android -T emulator
2) Once it loads go to your app directory and in the build directory under android->bin you'll find the app.apk
3) You can than use that .apk file to run on a device or another emulator